# raised tab bar and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I created an app with raised Tab Bar like that we see in applications such as Foursquare, Instagram or DailyBooth. To do that I put a UIButton at the center of the Tab Bar and everything seems OK, here the code in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 self.mainButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // set up the mainButton with an image and calculate coordinates

[self.mainButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMainViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:mainButton];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The mainButton has been defined in AppDelegate.h with its property (non atomic, retain) and synthesized.

By pushing the mainButton:

```
- (IBAction) showMainViewController:(id)sender {
    [self.mainButton setHidden:YES];
    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
    [self.mainNavController presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
    [nc release];
    [mainVC release];
}
```

Since the mainButton remain diplayed I decided to hide it.

At this point I have a doubt: I have to avoid hiding the button?

Problems comes when I decide to dismiss the MainViewController, I don't know if I'm working properly, I'm doing it by a simple `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in MainViewController.m
The result is that I'm not abled to unhide the mainButton by something like `[self.mainButton setHidden:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to unhide the button.

```
NSArray *array = self.tabBarController.view.subviews;
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        UIButton *uibtn = (UIButton *) [array objectAtIndex:i];
        uibtn.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```